# is there apprentice training in master of engineering?

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, masters, engineering

Do the M.Eng students in Electrical Engineering have apprenticeship? Do the students get money for their apprentice training? & how much?

Answer (score 3):

There really aren't "apprenticeships" associated with most traditional college degree programs. On the other hand, many engineering programs, including electrical engineering, do have what are usually known as *internship* or *co-op* (short for "cooperative learning") programs available. These programs are inherently designed to allow students to work in engineering-related companies during their degree program. The conditions that apply to each program are school-specific and even department-specific, so be sure to check with the individual departments you're interested in.

Comment: And, typically co-ops or internships in technical fields are paid some appreciable fraction market rates.

Comment: @MatthewG.: That is true in the US; that is not the case in some foreign countries (such as Germany).